# NA4 [Was] Splitting - Updating URLs On Buttons And Other Admin-Level Places (not Apex)

Tags: custom-button, administration, eclipse, xml, trust

Original question related to this:

[Searching "everything" in Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/26985/searching-everything-in-salesforce)

---

So there was an answer involving an "ant script", which is no use to me.  I am comfortable enough (I thought) with Eclipse (and have updated it and Java for this purpose) that I thought it would be the solution.

In Salesforce, I have a BUTTON defined which has a "Button or Link URL" defined with:

**https : //na4.salesforce.com/500/e?retURL=**
(the rest is irrelevant, space added to avoid a hotlink)

After refreshing the entire package in Eclipse, from Production SF, EXCEPT the emails and documents portions (too large), **Eclipse cannot find the above text**!

When I search for, let's say, **na4**, I find some references, but the closest I find to useful information is inside **objectTranslations**.

Can anyone give any guidance?

**NA4 is splitting**, and I'm trying to be thorough in finding ALL REFERENCES to it (URLs, obviously) so I can make them simply start at the slash so it's for "whatever cluster" it happens to be on ever again.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you make sure to check "objects - custom" and "objects - standard"?

Comment: Without pasting the list - yes.   Very much sure.   The sample I have in the Question above is from an Account custom button.   Frustrating.

Comment: Wait a (damn) minute.   Buttons are RECORDS?   https://na4.salesforce.com/00b60000000xZZZ   (sample URL of the example button in my question)

Comment: I do see with some more brief research that zero-zero-b is a weblink, aka CUSTOM_RESOURCE_LINK ... so now I'm wondering if I am to query a table in SF to do this search (at least for the BUTTONS).  EITHER WAY, "na4" is just NOT returning much in Eclipse.   Grr.

Comment: It would seem the question needs to be MODIFIED to ask... how can I MOST THOROUGHLY FIND all references "anywhere in SF, including object data" for "na4"?   I just queried the weblink table using Excel Connector and have all 154 records, no problem.   I'm just concerned I'm not going to find "all" NA4 refs in SF before the split, and just one will cause panic when a User clicks it or "accesses" it and it fails.

Comment: Since I seem to be answering this now that I've stumbled on info that is helping... so far, it would seem searching Eclipse's dump of our Org, AND doing a search in the CSVs of our weekly export of all objects, is "the answer" for now.  Until someone has something better  :-/

Comment: Aaaaaaand......   weblinks (and who knows what else) is not part of the weekly export service.  Searching for "na4" inside all CSVs except obvious ones yields zero results.  Life is great.   Going home for the day.